# How to test promise rejection with Mocha and Chai in Node?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I am trying to test my services and dao using Mocha and Chai. But, in Istanbul coverage, I am getting the 'reject' lines as red. Here is the code for a sample testing method.

```
describe('findAllCategories()', function() {
    it('should return all categories', function() {
        var stub = sinon.stub(categoryDao, 'findAllCategories');
        stub.callsFake(() => {
            return Promise.resolve(cat);
        });
        categoryService.findAllCategories().then(response => {
            assert.length(response, 1);
        }).catch(isError)
        .then((err) => {
            console.log(err);
          assert.isDefined(err);
        });
    })
});
```

Now, when I'm logging the error, it is showing "TypeError: assert.length is not a function".

Any way out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assert-library does not have a function `length`, but instead you can use `lengthOf()` (see https://www.chaijs.com/api/assert/ for more information):

```
assert.lengthOf(response, 1);
```

Comment: It is printing "AssertionError: expected { Object (id, name, ...) } to have property 'length'" now.

Comment: This means that your response object does not have a length property, meaning that it's not an array but an object. So you could just check if response is not undefined instead: `assert.isDefined(response);`

Comment: Thanks for the response. But, now I am getting "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: AssertionError: expected undefined to not equal undefined". The error is printing "undefined". Any way out?

Comment: By the way, I passed an array this time. So, it does have a length now.

Comment: If you passed an array and use the lengthOf-check, the first assertion should be fine, but you're probably getting the error from the line `assert.isDefined(err);`
What does `isError` do/return? If there's no error, err will be undefined in the then handler, hence the assertion failure.

Comment: Then how to check for the error as a test case? Another method?